# How to configure a livenessProbe in Kubernetes based Eclipse Microprofile

Tags: kubernetes, microprofile

I am running a rest service based on Eclipse Microprofile. My service provides a health check. The result of such a health check (which is providing a lot of information) looks for example like this:

```
http://localhost:9990/health
HTTP=OK

{
  "status":"UP",
  "checks":[
    {"name":"imixs-workflow",
     "status":"UP",
     "data":
     {
     "engine.version":"5.1.11-SNAPSHOT",
     "model.groups":30,
     "model.versions":20
     }
    }
  ]
}
```

The service is healthy if the check named 'imixs-workflow' shows the 'status' 'UP'.

I already tried to configure this with a livenessprobe like this:

```
livenessProbe:
  exec:
    command: ["sh", "-c", "curl -s http://localhost:9990/health| grep -q imixs-workflow"]
  initialDelaySeconds: 60
```

But this did not work.

How should I configure such a livenessprobe getting the status of a specific json field in a http result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your liveness probe command should return status different from 0 to indicate unhealthy container condition. Please see [Configure Liveness, Readiness and Startup Probes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-liveness-readiness-startup-probes/).

If possible, I'd also recommend for better maintainability and readability to use the tool called [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) - command-line JSON processor.

With it your probe should look something like this:

```
livenessProbe:
  exec:
    command: ["sh", "-c", "curl -s http://localhost:9990/health | jq -e '.checks[] | select(.name == "imixs-workflow") | .status == "UP"']
  initialDelaySeconds: 60
```

Here `-e` flag sets exit status to 1 if the last output value was false.